# Cygwinのデフォルトのペーストキーを変更する方法について。

Tags: windows, cygwin

Cygwinをwindows7で使用しているのですが
Cygwinのデフォルトのペーストが ctrlキー + insキーとなっております。

これを ctrl + v キー に変更することは出来ないでしょうか。
ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けないでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。
そもそもキー変更が可能か不可能かさえも不明な状態なので、もし不可能であるようならば一言「不可能」と仰って頂ければ助かります。

*cygwinはこちらのページのセットアップツールを使って導入致しました。
https://cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+Vは特殊な意味があるので割り当てられないと思います。

かわりの方法としては、Cygwinのターミナルエミュレータ(Mintty)で `Cntrol + Shift + v` でペーストすることは設定変更で可能です。

ターミナル上を右クリック→ Options → Keys → `Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts` をチェックしてください。

蛇足ですが、TeraTerm(Cyglaunch)を使えば `alt + v` でペーストできます。

Comment: take88様
回答ありがとうございます！
完璧です！
望んでいたことが出来ました。

Answer (score 2):

Cygwinのホームディレクトリの下に設定ファイル「.minttyrc」を作成して

```
ClipShortcuts=no
CtrlExchangeShift=true
KeyFunctions=c:copy;v:paste
```

の記述をしておけばCtrl+Cでコピー、Ctrl+Vでペーストが可能。